# How to use one container in pipeline?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

the situation is such that we move from jenkins to gitlab ci. Every time a stage occurs in the pipeline, a new container is created, I would like to know if it is possible to make the container used by the previous one, that is, a single one. Gitlab Executer is docker.
I want to save condition of one container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible in a practical way with the docker executor. Each *job* is executed in its own container. There is no setting to change this behavior.

Keep in mind that jobs (even across stages) can run concurrently and that jobs can land on runners on completely different underlying machines. Therefore, this is not really practical.